# SQL Case When with multiple row inserts

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, sql-insert

I'm working on a logistics system with inputs from our users.

I'm using [GAPTEQ](https://gapteq.com/), an application that uses simple drag-and-drop components to create interactive websites. Within GAPTEQ you can create SQL-statements for data queries, inserts and updates as well as session variables and site parameters to store data while having the session open.

Below is a screenshot of the TileView component, which act like buttons when pressed.

[image: User Interface]

Upon pressing any button the value shown is saved as a variable and the SQL-statement is being executed.

A "normal" statement would looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.table (row1, row2, row3) VALUES (val1, @Input_User, val3)
```

The value of the variable, which has the value of the pressed tile, is being inserted for row2.

Now, imagine the user wants 3 pallets to be picked up:
Since the forklift can only pick up one pallet at the time I have to create 3 transport orders out of one button press.

I tried using a `Case When` statement that looked somewhat like this:

```
CASE @Input_User <---- parameter by GAPTEQ which has the value of the pressed tile
WHEN '1 Palette' THEN INSERT INTO table(row1, row2 ,row3) VALUES (val1, val2, val3)
WHEN '2 Paletten' THEN INSERT INTO table(row1, row2 ,row3) VALUES (val1, val2, val3), (val1, val2, val3)
...
```

which didn't work. My intent was to insert two rows for '2 Paletten', three for '3 Paletten' and so on.

What I'm looking for is a way to make as many inserts as the tile the user presses shows with a single sql statement (if that is even possible).

What ways are there?

EDIT: Changed the question quite a bit for clarity. I hope it is much more understandable now.

Comment: Each make and version of database server has its own dialect of SQL. But none of them allow the syntax you show in your question. So we can help you, please [edit] your question to add a [tag](//stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database you use. [tag:postgresql]? [tag:mysql]? [tag:sql-server]? [tag:oracle]? [tag:google-bigquery]? [tag:amazon-redshift]? Another?

Comment: Oops, added the appropriate tag.

Comment: Going to need more detail about your questions here because it is not clear at all what you are asking -- do you want to know how to pass more than one row of parameters to a SP?

Comment: Please give us more details about what you are asking. As it stands, I have no clue what exact your question is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at this again I think you want a table value parameter then you can just do the following (without the case statement)

```
 INSERT INTO YOURTABLE
    SELECT * FROM TABLEVALUEPARAM
```

In fact the Microsoft page on TVP has this exact example as their first example.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Not exactly what I'm looking for right now but something I'll need later on, so thank you from my "future me" :-). It's hard do describe exactly what I'm looking for. I'll update the question to make it as clear as possible.

Comment: @SikorskyS60 -- probably a good idea to do that if you want an answer that solves your problem.

Comment: ok @SikorskyS60 -- I looked at your changes and my answer still seems correct -- in what way won't it work?

Comment: Read it through again today. I can use it for my problem. Thank you :-)